# How can I control the mouse scroll event and after that do an animation on the html, body?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm facing a very strange error, which is animation on body during mouse scroll. I think its happening because of the `jQuery` event `window.scroll`. I have tried a lot of things like unbinding of animation on mouse scroll, but nothing works. Below is my code.

```js
$(document).on("scroll", function () {

  var lastScrollTop = 0;
  var windowHeight = $(window).scrollTop();
  var seccion1 = $("#seccion1").height();
  var seccion2 = $("#seccion2").offset().top;
  var alturaseccion2 = $("#seccion2").height();

//this function returns in which section is the user with the scroll
  var localizacion = comprobarSeccion(seccion1, seccion2);

  if (windowHeight > lastScrollTop) {
    // down scroll 

    console.log("scrollabajo");

    if (localizacion == 1) {
      $("html, body").animate({
        scrollTop: $("#seccion2").offset().top
      }, 2);
      $(document).bind("scroll");
    } else if (localizacion == 2) {

      if (windowHeight >= ((alturaseccion2 * 0.80) + seccion2) && windowHeight <= (alturaseccion2 + seccion2)) {
      } else {
      }
    }

  } else {
    // up scroll 

    console.log("scrollarriba");
  }
  lastScrollTop = windowHeight;
});
´´´
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish, but if your trying to trigger an event with a specific scroll value you can use the code below

```
 $(window).scroll(function () { 
        var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();

        if (scroll >= 500) {
             alert("scroll is greater than 500 px)
        } else if(scroll==500){
            alert("scroll has hit 500px");
        }

    });
```

Comment: Iam trying to do an animation to all the page when the user do scroll down or up.

Comment: yup, you can put your animation inside that function. it will be triggered everytime you scroll.. try to putting an `alert("anything");` inside that function to test if its working

Comment: Hi warren thats what iam doing in my code but when it does the animation, it detects that it is doing scroll, and it triggers again the animation causing that another time because of the animation, moves the scroll, and triggered all the process again.